# How to search the value of current column in another column then display it's id in another column adjacent to it in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataframe there are 4 columns col1,col1_id,col2,col2_id, I want to locate col_2 values in col_1 then if is there any match respective col1_id should be append to col2_id.

```
 col_1  col1_id col_2  col2_id
    A        1   NaN      NaN
    B        2     K      NaN
    D        3     A      NaN
    J        4   NaN      NaN
    E        5     H      NaN
    Z        6   NaN      NaN
    H        7     H      NaN
    K        8     Z      NaN
```

Any help??, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solution and it seems output of first look better.

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary `d` created with columns `col_1` and `col1_id`:

```
d = df[['col_1','col1_id']].set_index('col_1').to_dict()
print d
{'col1_id': {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'E': 5, 'D': 3, 'H': 7, 'K': 8, 'J': 4, 'Z': 6}}

df['col2_id'] = df.col_2.map(d['col1_id'])
print df
  col_1  col1_id col_2  col2_id
0     A        1   NaN      NaN
1     B        2     K      8.0
2     D        3     A      1.0
3     J        4   NaN      NaN
4     E        5     H      7.0
5     Z        6   NaN      NaN
6     H        7     H      7.0
7     K        8     Z      6.0
```

Or you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
print df.col_1.isin(df.col_2)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
Name: col_1, dtype: bool

df['col2_id'] = df.col1_id.where(df.col_1.isin(df.col_2))
print df
  col_1  col1_id col_2  col2_id
0     A        1   NaN      1.0
1     B        2     K      NaN
2     D        3     A      NaN
3     J        4   NaN      NaN
4     E        5     H      NaN
5     Z        6   NaN      6.0
6     H        7     H      7.0
7     K        8     Z      8.0
```

**Timings**:

```
def pil(df):
    df = df.set_index('col_1')
    df['col2_id'] = df.col_2.apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else df.loc[x, 'col1_id'])
    return df.reset_index()

def jez(df):
    df['col2_id'] = df.col_2.map(df.set_index('col_1').to_dict()['col1_id'])
    return df

print pil(df1)
print jez(df)

In [34]: %timeit jez(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.48 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit pil(df1)
The slowest run took 4.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.56 ms per loop
```

Comment: Please check solutions and if output can be different, you can add desired  to question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df.set_index('col_1')
df['col2_id'] = df.col_2.apply(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else df.loc[x, 'col1_id'])
df = df.reset_index()

df

  col_1  col1_id col_2  col2_id
0     A        1   NaN      NaN
1     B        2     K      8.0
2     D        3     A      1.0
3     J        4   NaN      NaN
4     E        5     H      7.0
5     Z        6   NaN      NaN
6     H        7     H      7.0
7     K        8     Z      6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this problem looks like a standard task in RDBMS. So you can use merge()

```
df['col2_id'] = pd.merge(df, df[['col1', 'col1_id']], left_on='col2', right_on='col1', how='left')['col1_id_y']
```